# How can a class be accessible for one form, and not for the other?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am making a very basic 2d (top-down) "game". Therefore I use 2 forms. One for the UI (UIForm) and the other one for the visual part of the game (Form1, also the first form to be loaded). Also I have a class wich defines different animal species and provides properties like the size.

However, it seems like I cannot access the Species class from my Form1 since I have created UIForm (which has access to the species class).

This will give an IndexOutOfRange exception:

```
private Species species = new Species();
int i = this.species.size[1];
```

This is working though:

```
int i = UIForm.species.size[1];
```

Here I have made species public in UIForm for the sake of testing and used that to access the class Species. This works, so I could work around it, but how do I fix this? And why does this happen?

I was used to be able to access the species class from form1 before i had made the UIForm.

I'm sorry if I am too vague or if it's very obvious, but I am still a noob at this.

(B.T.W. There is no threading going on)

Comment: is `UIForm` the *type* ? or a *reference to an instance* ? Because `UIForm.species` should *not* work if `UIForm` is the type, since `species` is an instance field, not static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks as though species is a property/field on `UIForm` and when you are using it in your next form, you are assigning a `new` instance of species to a variable.`

```
private Sepcies species = new Species() // wrong
private Species species = UIForm.species // possibly right
```

Or better yet

```
private Species GetUISpecies()
{
    return UIForm.species;
}
```

Comment: everything is set as private, none of what you have written will be accessible from outside of the class in which it was defined.

Comment: @bizzehdee -  have read it as the OP has made a new variable called `species` in Form1, this is private, `UIForm.species` is not which is why it appears to work for them. I have written private in my examples to keep them local to `Form1`

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `species` as `private` within the form, so you cannot access it from outside of that form. you need to declare it as `public`, along with declaring `size` as `public` within the `Species` class

Comment: caveat: simply changing the accessibility of a field to `public` is almost never the right choice

Comment: Right or wrong, it is the answer to the question that is being asked. I am not here to give advice, i am here to give an answer to the exact question asked.

Comment: The question states *"I have made species public in UIForm"* underneath the second code example.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` for your first example. This is because there are less than two elements in that Species' instance's size array.

In the second example, the size array has at least 2 elements, which is why you can access the element at index 1 at that point.

The conclusion is that somewhere between, the size array gets recreated with a larger size, or the species variable ends up pointing to a different instance. Run your code through the debugger, and see how it interacts with the species variable/size array.