# C# How to access a class from two different forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am having a big problem wich I cannot solve myself.

I have got two windows forms running at the same time and a separate class. To interact with the class I use this code in both forms:

```
private Entities entities = new Entities();
```

I use that in one of my forms, like so:

```
int hp = entities.Get_HP(CurrentEntity);
```

Here hp will be for example 90 or 57... But when I do the exact same thing in the other form, then it will thow an exception saying that entities.Get_HP(CurrentEntity) is null. The debugger (vs 2012) says the same.

This only happens in one form, not the other.

I really hope someone can help me with this, because I'm clueless.
Thank you, Dion Dokter.

Comment: How are you sharing the instance entities. Are you setting it with a property?

Comment: Is one form opening the other?

Comment: You asked the same question pretty much this morning, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078098/how-can-a-class-be-accessible-for-one-form-and-not-for-the-other)

Comment: A class with singleton pattern used would do the job

Comment: @Sayse True, but I didn't get a good answer. I think my question wasn't clear enough..

Comment: Can I ask what was unclear about my answer? because the two answers below say the same thing in different words

Comment: Sorry, I will do that the next time... @Sayse I just couldn't figure out what you exactly meant. I have tried, but failed to get it right.

Comment: @Patrick Yes indeed. Is something else recommended?

Comment: @Geoxion: Yes to what?

Comment: @Patrick I assume he means [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087682/c-sharp-how-to-access-a-class-from-two-different-forms#comment26474807_18087682).

Comment: @Geoxion No, having one form open the other is fine, it's just that knowing that is quite relevant to the question.  The problem would be approached differently if they were, for example, independent of each other and both opened by some 3rd class.  Which form opens the other, and which form needs to create the entities object?

Comment: I have got it working now thank you guys for your input, you have made me smile.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is null? Is it the variable entities or CurrentEntity? What is CurrentEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form1 change you Entities declaration to something like;

```
private static Entities entities = new Entities();

public static GetEntities() { return entities }
```

In Form2

```
private Entities entities;
private bool entitiesSet = false;
```

Where you're gonna use entities;

```
if (!entitiesSet)
   entities = Form1.GetEntities();
```

Just make sure there is no code path that attempts to access methods/properties of entities before it is set in Form2 and this should do it. Not sure where this implementation stands with regard to good or bad practice as I don't work with controllers/winforms but it will definitely work.

Comment: I'm surely going to try this out. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure recommending using a static field is the best advice..?

Comment: This type of data doesn't appear to be conceptually static at all, as such it shouldn't be in a static field; that's not the appropriate way of sharing the data here.  Either there's a relationship between the forms that isn't discussed in the OP, in which one should provide the information to the other, or both have a common parent, in which that parent should provide the object to both forms.

Comment: @Patrick "Not sure where this implementation stands with regard to good or bad practice as I don't work with controllers/winforms but it will definitely work." Perhaps not an assumption I should be making but I get the feeling the OP is not writing a serious program and while the solution Servy suggests sounds a lot better for a robust enterprise application it's probably a bit of a stretch for an intro to C# homework assignment or whatever the OP is working on.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That this is an intro assignment makes it all the more important for the OP to learn how to solve this problem *properly*.  If they learn poor practices early on they are then forced to either unlearn them and then attempt to learn proper practices when dealing with complex problems rather than simpler ones, or (more likely) end up continuing to apply the poor practices on the larger more complex projects and create unmaintainable, incomprehensible messes that nobody can work with.

Comment: But learning bad practices from the start will not help him make enterprise application in the future.

Comment: @Servy I feel like you're pretty far removed from academia because pretty much every project I did was a complete joke where every other line of code would not pass a code review at any of the companies I've worked for...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal So that means you should encourage others to write equally poor code in their education, instead of helping them to learn proper methods from the start, thus giving them a dramatically better learning experience in programming?  Or do you really think that learning poor practices in school and then learning good practices once you get a job is actually the better way to learn?

Comment: @Servy I don't think this is really the place for this discussion. I'd just like to point out I never said it was good practice, in fact, I said the opposite. You're welcome to contact me in private chat or some other means if you want to continue the debate but enough of the comments. The OP got what was needed and likely something along the lines of what was expected.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal You didn't say the opposite, you said you didn't know if it was good practice or not.  I'm telling you that it's not.  Not only is it not good, it's a particularly harmful practice to use in the winform world.  It seems very tempting at first, but it very quickly becomes unusable in all but the most trivial applications, and yet becomes a real crutch that developers have a very hard time getting over once they've gotten used to it.  And whether or not it's appropriate to use this solution is most certainly something appropriate to discuss here.  (FYI, SO has no private chat.)

Answer (score 2):

Each time you say "new" you're getting an entirely *unique* instance of the object.  What you want is the *same* instrance between the two different windows. You could use events to pass around information, or a static method somewhere, or have the windows have a custom constructor(s) with parameter(s) to share the object(s).

These are core concepts.  Someone can help further if you detail your usage of your program, specifically how these forms are opened.

Comment: Dependency injection is probably the way to go, at least if the two forms have some sort of link between them (one opening the other for instance). The "static method" I don't approve with though, the entities field is not static in the OP so what good would a static *method* do?

Comment: @Patrick I listed examples of means to accomplish the general idea here - data access between two forms. OP did not state nature of forms, just that there were two forms and a class, so was going broad in concepts. Static lists can be useful, to keep all objects for querying and/or disposal; they can also be easily abused. A (public) static method to retrieve a particular item from that (private) list by LINQ would work. Best approach here? Probably not. Just providing ideas.